# How do I solve this complex windowing query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I have a flight database to track ultralight flights of various aircraft. The motors on these aircraft consist of parts which need replacing at a certain number of flying hours elapsed, which varies depending on the part. My database has the following tables (included below with sample data):

- **Motors**: Information about the motor in the aircraft
- **MotorParts**: A list of parts for each motor and when this part needs replacing
- **MotorPartServiceHistory**: A log of when the part was replaced with the date
- **Flights**: A log of each flight flown by each motor

Views:

- **FlightDetails**: Shows the duration of each flight and the total hours flown for the motor

I need to know when a part on a motor needs replacing.

So, I need a query that returns all the columns from `MotorParts` with an additional two columns:

- `HoursSinceReplacement`: number of hours flown since last replaced. If NULL then total hours for the motor.
- `Status`: values of either `OK` or `Replace`. It should show `Replace` if `HoursSinceReplacement` is greater than the `ReplaceHours` value in `MotorParts`, otherwise return `OK`.

I am struggling to figure this out. If you add the `MotorParts` sample data row by row you should see the `Status` column changing from `OK` to `Replace` each time you run the query.

**Schema**

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS [dbo].[FlightDetails]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Flights]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[MotorPartServiceHistory]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[MotorParts]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Motors]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Motors]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , [Manufacturer] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , [Model] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , [Engine] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , [EngineCC] TINYINT NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MotorParts]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [PartName] VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
    [PartNumber] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [MotorId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ReplaceHours] TINYINT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MotorParts_Motors] FOREIGN KEY ([MotorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Motors]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MotorParts] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [AK_MotorParts_MotorIdPartName] UNIQUE ([PartName],[MotorId])
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_MotorParts_PartNumber] ON [dbo].[MotorParts] ([PartNumber])
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MotorPartServiceHistory]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [PartId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MotorPartServiceHistory_MotorParts] FOREIGN KEY ([PartId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MotorParts]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MotorPartServiceHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id])
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [MotorPartServiceHistory_DatePartId] ON [dbo].[MotorPartServiceHistory] ([Date], [PartId])
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Flights]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [TakeOffTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [LandingTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [MotorId] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Flights] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[FlightDetails]
    AS 

SELECT f.[Id] as [Flight]
    ,f.[Date]
    ,DATENAME (dw, f.[Date]) as DoW
    ,f.[MotorId]
    ,[TakeOffTime]
    ,[LandingTime]
    ,CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime]),'00:00:00') AS time) as Duration
    ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime]) as DurationMinutes
    ,CAST ((SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime])) OVER (PARTITION BY f.MotorId ORDER BY f.[Id])/60.0) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) as TotalHours
FROM [dbo].[Flights] f
GO
```

**Sample data to play around with**

```
INSERT [dbo].[Motors] ([Id], [Manufacturer], [Model], [Engine], [EngineCC]) VALUES (1, N'Parajet', N'Maverick', N'Moster', 185)
INSERT [dbo].[Motors] ([Id], [Manufacturer], [Model], [Engine], [EngineCC]) VALUES (2, N'Scout', N'Enduro', N'Atom', 80)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MotorParts] ([Id], [PartName], [PartNumber], [MotorId], [ReplaceHours]) VALUES (1, N'Oil for reduction gear', N'AT160', 2, 10)
INSERT [dbo].[MotorParts] ([Id], [PartName], [PartNumber], [MotorId], [ReplaceHours]) VALUES (2, N'Starter Rope (2m)', N'M043', 1, 20)
INSERT [dbo].[MotorParts] ([Id], [PartName], [PartNumber], [MotorId], [ReplaceHours]) VALUES (3, N'Spark plug', N'M020', 1, 18)
INSERT [dbo].[MotorParts] ([Id], [PartName], [PartNumber], [MotorId], [ReplaceHours]) VALUES (4, N'Exhaust bushing', N'MY202', 1, 25)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2023-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'17:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'20:00:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2023-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'06:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'10:00:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2023-08-04' AS Date), CAST(N'07:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'08:30:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2023-08-05' AS Date), CAST(N'09:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'13:00:00' AS Time), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2023-08-06' AS Date), CAST(N'10:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'16:00:00' AS Time), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2023-08-08' AS Date), CAST(N'05:30:00' AS Time), CAST(N'07:30:00' AS Time), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2023-08-09' AS Date), CAST(N'09:45:00' AS Time), CAST(N'12:15:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2023-08-10' AS Date), CAST(N'16:15:00' AS Time), CAST(N'20:00:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2023-08-11' AS Date), CAST(N'12:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'17:00:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2023-08-12' AS Date), CAST(N'06:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'10:00:00' AS Time), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2023-08-13' AS Date), CAST(N'07:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'09:00:00' AS Time), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2023-08-14' AS Date), CAST(N'08:15:00' AS Time), CAST(N'12:00:00' AS Time), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (13, CAST(N'2023-08-15' AS Date), CAST(N'09:45:00' AS Time), CAST(N'11:20:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (14, CAST(N'2023-08-16' AS Date), CAST(N'10:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'14:00:00' AS Time), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [MotorId]) VALUES (15, CAST(N'2023-08-17' AS Date), CAST(N'08:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'11:00:00' AS Time), 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MotorPartServiceHistory] ([Id], [PartId], [Date]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(N'2023-08-08' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[MotorPartServiceHistory] ([Id], [PartId], [Date]) VALUES (2, 3, CAST(N'2023-08-14' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[MotorPartServiceHistory] ([Id], [PartId], [Date]) VALUES (3, 2, CAST(N'2023-08-16' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[MotorPartServiceHistory] ([Id], [PartId], [Date]) VALUES (4, 4, CAST(N'2023-08-18' AS Date))
GO
```

**Expected results**

If `MotorPartServiceHistory` is empty the results should be

| Id | PartName | PartNumber | MotorId | ReplaceHours | HoursSinceReplacement | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oil for reduction gear | AT160 | 2 | 10 | 21.75 | Replace |
| 2 | Starter Rope (2m) | M043 | 1 | 20 | 28.3 | Replace |
| 3 | Spark plug | M020 | 1 | 18 | 28.3 | Replace |
| 4 | Exhaust bushing | MY202 | 1 | 25 | 28.3 | Replace |

After entering Id=1 from the sample data in `MotorPartServiceHistory` the query should look like:

| Id | PartName | PartNumber | MotorId | ReplaceHours | HoursSinceReplacement | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oil for reduction gear | AT160 | 2 | 10 | 9.75 | OK |
| 2 | Starter Rope (2m) | M043 | 1 | 20 | 28.3 | Replace |
| 3 | Spark plug | M020 | 1 | 18 | 28.3 | Replace |
| 4 | Exhaust bushing | MY202 | 1 | 25 | 28.3 | Replace |

After entering Id=2 from the sample data in `MotorPartServiceHistory` the query should look like:

| Id | PartName | PartNumber | MotorId | ReplaceHours | HoursSinceReplacement | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oil for reduction gear | AT160 | 2 | 10 | 9.75 | OK |
| 2 | Starter Rope (2m) | M043 | 1 | 20 | 8.6 | OK |
| 3 | Spark plug | M020 | 1 | 18 | 28.3 | Replace |
| 4 | Exhaust bushing | MY202 | 1 | 25 | 28.3 | Replace |

After entering Id=3 from the sample data in `MotorPartServiceHistory` the query should look like:

| Id | PartName | PartNumber | MotorId | ReplaceHours | HoursSinceReplacement | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oil for reduction gear | AT160 | 2 | 10 | 9.75 | OK |
| 2 | Starter Rope (2m) | M043 | 1 | 20 | 8.6 | OK |
| 3 | Spark plug | M020 | 1 | 18 | 3 | OK |
| 4 | Exhaust bushing | MY202 | 1 | 25 | 28.3 | Replace |

After entering Id=4 from the sample data in `MotorPartServiceHistory` the query should look like:

| Id | PartName | PartNumber | MotorId | ReplaceHours | HoursSinceReplacement | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oil for reduction gear | AT160 | 2 | 10 | 9.75 | OK |
| 2 | Starter Rope (2m) | M043 | 1 | 20 | 8.6 | OK |
| 3 | Spark plug | M020 | 1 | 18 | 3 | OK |
| 4 | Exhaust bushing | MY202 | 1 | 25 | 0 | OK |

Comment: Where is it, exactly, you are getting stuck? What is your attempt so far? You've provided sample data, in a consumable format (***thank you***) but no expected results for that data either.

Comment: Based on the example data what is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I have provided sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it still can be done without window functions. The query is split for the sake of readability:

```
WITH TimeSinceReplacement AS (
    SELECT
        MotorParts.Id AS Id,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TakeOffTime, LandingTime)) AS TotalMinutes
    FROM
        MotorParts AS MotorParts
        INNER JOIN Flights AS FlightHistory
            ON MotorParts.MotorId = FlightHistory.MotorId
        LEFT JOIN (
            -- Query the last service date for each motor part
            SELECT 
                ServiceHistory.PartId AS PartId,
                MAX(ServiceHistory.Date) AS ServiceDate
            FROM 
                MotorPartServiceHistory AS ServiceHistory
            GROUP BY 
                ServiceHistory.PartId) AS LastServiceDate
        ON  LastServiceDate.PartId = MotorParts.Id
    WHERE 
        -- Leave only the flight records, 
        -- which are strictly after the last service date
        ISNULL(LastServiceDate.ServiceDate, '0001-01-01') < FlightHistory.Date
    GROUP BY
        MotorParts.Id)
```

```
SELECT
    MotorParts.Id AS Id,
    MotorParts.PartName AS PartName,
    MotorParts.PartNumber AS PartNumber,  
    MotorParts.MotorId AS MotorId,
    MotorParts.ReplaceHours AS ReplaceHours,
    CAST(
        ISNULL(TimeSinceReplacement.TotalMinutes, 0) / 60.0 
        AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS HoursSinceReplacement,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(TimeSinceReplacement.TotalMinutes, 0) 
                        > MotorParts.ReplaceHours * 60 
        THEN 'Replace' 
        ELSE 'OK' 
    END AS [Status]
 FROM 
    MotorParts AS MotorParts
    -- There won't be replacement records, 
    -- if maintenance was not after the last flight
    LEFT JOIN TimeSinceReplacement AS TimeSinceReplacement
        ON MotorParts.Id = TimeSinceReplacement.Id
```

Few remarks:

- Ids in sample service history do not follow the description: records with ids `2` and `3` lead to the reversed parts: `3` and `2`.
- 20 minutes are converted to `0.33` hours and 35 minutes - to `0.58` hours. In contrary to the expected results, which are `0.3` and `0.6`.